# Ping works, wireless connected, no stable internet

Tags: networking, wireless, ssh, scp

I have an old (2014) laptop that I've converted into a Linux desktop at home, mostly for storing extra stuff over `scp`. Today, the network of this machine slowed to a crawl. All packs installation hover around 50kB/s, firefox doesn't load any page, but `ping` and `curl` still works. I tried to ssh to and from other computer at home (all others works fine), the ssh terminal is regularly interrupted, freezing for 3-5 seconds before resuming normal for 2-3 seconds. What is going on? Have any of you had similar problems? Do you think it's a hardware problem related to wifi card? This machine worked fine up until morning today.

Comment: Try different DNS - for example put in /etc/resolv.conf  `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network that is loaded down (maybe).

It sounds like this is connected wirelessly. You might consider using an ethernet cable if possible -- it would sidestep any wireless problem -- even if it is just as a test.

You also might try changing your wifi channel. You can do this in your wifi router under the wifi settings. If you have an android device, you could consider using something like the Wifi Analyzer app to see what channels have other networks on them and try to stay away (by a few channels) from busy channels.

Or, you could just have another wireless device on your home network that is moving a lot of traffic. (Is the wifi light on your router running at a constant flicker? If so, it may be busy moving data and the wifi might be congested.)